# How can I go to red line of error in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

My question is if there is any command that allows me to go to the red error line in Eclipse. For example, I am in line 1 of my file and there is an error in line 1200 – is there any way to go directly to that line? (Obviously, I don't know the line number, so I don't use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.)

Comment: If you look at the Problems view you can double click on any message there to go directly to the error in any file.

Answer (score 0):

As the commenter said, you can do this from the problems view, but there are ways to navigate somewhat efficiently in the source view.

While your cursor is in a file in the source view, the function "next" might be bound to "Ctrl+." (control-period).  This is implemented in various scopes to do different things, but in the source view, it goes to the next "issue" in the file.  If your only issue in the file is the error, then that keypress will bring you to that line.

In addition, the right-hand margin of the source view contains a column that spans the entire file.  If there is an error on a line, you'll see a red horizontal block in that column.  The height of the block would likely be relative to the size of the file.  You can click on points in that column to go to that portion of the file, so if you click on the red mark, it will land close to that line.